# Javascript issue with object type in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, javascript-objects

There is a strange issue with IE-8 I have !
I have 3 javascript files in my project

This is my code in first JSFile1:

```
function validate(p){
  return p !== undefined;
}
```

and this is my second file JSFile2:

```
function myfunc(p){
  if(validate(p.class) && validate(p.n1) && validate(p.n2))
     alert(p.class + ' ' + p.n1*p.n2);//    doSomething
}
```

and this is the last js file: JSFile3:

```
var virtual={
  class:860,
  another:'good',
  type:'ask'
};
// here is function
$(document).ready(function(){
  myfunc({
    class:'my value',
    n1:3,
    n2:5
  });
});
```

In firefox I have no trouble but in IE-8 log shows me these errors :

```
Expected identifier
string or number Expected identifier
```

Comment: I don't know what is between class in `virtual` and class in parameter of `myfunc` ! they have nothing to do with each other !

Comment: Which line is causing that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class` is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), you have to quote it.

```
var virtual={
  'class':860,
  another:'good',
  type:'ask'
};
// here is function
$(document).ready(function(){
  myfunc({
    'class':'my value',
    n1:3,
    n2:5
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words
class is a `reserved` **keyword**